# Why does a garage gas heater need 8' clearance from the ground when a home furnace sits on the ground?

Tags: hvac, furnace, garage, heater

[This unit](https://www.princessauto.com/en/50000-btu-natural-gas-unit-heater-with-lp-conversion-kit/product/PA0008944951) comes at the price of a wall direct vent propane heater but it requires 8' clearance from the ground. Why does it need that clearance when a regular direct vent furnace even with a higher capacity sits on the slab in the basement?

Comment: Ceiling mounted and I think the 8ft clearance is probably so it does not burn the paint off of cars.  Aircraft hangers need 10ft above airplanes.

Comment: you compared heating capacity, but what about the output air temperature? And possibly with vs. without safety features to detect in/out flow blocking?

Comment: Do you think that the wall unit is better in those respects ?

Comment: It might be an argument similar to this one: The clearance is to prevent fires or explosions if a flammable liquid (such as gasoline or motor oil) spills on the garage floor. If you install an electric water heater or a gas water heater with a sealed combustion chamber, this requirement may not apply to you.Jun 29, 2021◄ but this is for a water heater

Comment: You can't walk or drive under your home's furnace.

Comment: You might have local codes that might require professional installation/inspection.  Depending on the use of the woodshop, will also have sawdust to be aware of.  A build up of sawdust near the unit might cause interesting effects.

Comment: totally agree with both of you but 8' clearance ? I am not 8' tall neither do I have 8' piles of sawdust

Comment: @MiniMe the rules aren't made with you specifically in mind - they're made to be generally applicable to everyone. Just because you're using your garage as a woodworking space (as do I) doesn't mean that the person you sell the house to eventually will do the same thing. If they resume using it as a garage then the space still has to function safely as a garage - so you're not allowed to do something which prevents that. Perhaps if you walled up the garage door to *permanently* convert the space then you'd no longer have to comply with the 'garage' rules.

Comment: Your question can only result in speculation. Perhaps reformulate to ask about the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: @brhans The next owners can take the entire house up to the code if they want to. I am worried about real accidents not about blanket code specs that force me to dig 1Km into the ground for a fence post because they do so in Yukon :-))

Comment: Had an installer have a look at it and he said he is going to install it but not going to put his tag on it :D So for a nice fee all the code can be ignored

Comment: How would the next owners know that you've created a code violation which needs to be fixed? I assume you're going to lie on your seller disclosure and say that there's no un-permitted work taken place in the house...? If they do use the garage as an actual garage and your unsafe non-code-compliant installation results in a fire and loss of life - how would you plan to recover from that?

Comment: What are you smoking ? Even today in this market you do not sign any paper other than the sale contract. House sold as is, seller unable to asses if work is done by code or not even if it was done by contractors that nobody remembers. You must be nuts to sign such paper and the potential buyer is sent back to his or her origins if that sort of question is asked. In certain areas of each country it is a seller market no matter what the economy is and BTW you can/must hire a home inspector as buyer. Geee !

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://www.garagejournal.com/forum/threads/minimum-ceiling-height-for-a-hanging-heater.171232/) seems to explain some of the reasons:

- clearance for vehicles that might hit it or get burnt by the radiant heat
- some opinions say it is also for gas and fumes but I do not get the point because this is a direct vent unit so all that should go straight out through the direct vent
- also to keep the unit away from flammable gases and oils

In my case this is a garage turned into a woodworking and storage space.

Update:See page 39 of [this](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Natural-Gas-and-Propane-Installation-Handbook-CSA-B149.pdf) document. Handbook CSA-B149 it explains the rationale for the 8’ requirement and clarifies it is for a “repair garage” while it is 18” for a “storage garage”. As always, at the end of the day it is up to your local code enforcement to decide what is acceptable